# Preg Match not match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a string and I want to take only matched word which contain only integer value not float or character.

Example :

```
2.0 Test map
2.0 Your Word 150
2.0 Your 150  Word
```

from first sting nothing take but second string get 150

I am using `/\b([0-9])\b/i` but not work

Comment: I suggest matching and skipping floats, and only match other digit chunks: `preg_match_all('~\d*\.\d+(?:e[-+]?\d+)?(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+~i', $s, $matches)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1gj8I/1).

Comment: You may use lookarounds: [`(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/9lI0HS/3)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ignore `.` as you dont want float numbers: try follwoing expression

```
/(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.])/
```

Comment: `(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.])` will match `345` in `1.23+e345`. Sure, it might not be a problem for OP, just FYI.